# memcpy in Abstract Data Type List Array based in C

Tags: c

I'm currently struggling to understand how an array of structures works. For reference, here is the complete code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 14
/******************************************************************
 * Data Structure Definition                                      *
 ******************************************************************/
typedef struct {
  unsigned int prodID;    /*  product ID, uniquely identifies an element */ 
  char prodDesc[50];      /*  product description*/  
  float prodPrice;        /*  product price*/  
  int prodQty;            /* product count or quantity  */
}product, products[SIZE];                 /* product record */

typedef struct cell {
   products item;             /* array of products */
   int prodCtr;           /* number of products in the list */
}*chocoList;              /*  Definition of the ADT List ver 2 */  

typedef enum {
    TRUE, FALSE
}boolean;

/******************************************************************
 * Function Prototypes                                            *
 ******************************************************************/
void initializeList(chocoList *L);             
void populateSortedList(chocoList L);         
void displayList(chocoList L, char * listName);
void displayProduct(product X);                 
int insertSorted(chocoList L, product X);    
product deleteFirstOccurence(chocoList L, float prodPrice);

int main(void) 
{
    chocoList  L;      /* sorted List  */
    product deleted;     /* container for the deleted record */

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * Problem #1 :: Initialize the choco list. Display the products in the list after* 
    * calling populateSortedList().                                                  *
    * printf("\n\n\nProblem #1:: ");                                                 *
    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    printf("\n\n\nProblem #1:: ");
    initializeList(&L); 
    populateSortedList(L);
    displayList(L, "Problem 1");

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * Problem #2 :: Delete 1 product from the list by calling deleteFirstOccurence(). * 
    * Display the returned product record by calling displayProduct().               *
    * printf("\n\n\nProblem #2:: ");                                                 *
    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    printf("\n\n\nProblem #2:: ");     
    deleted = deleteFirstOccurence(L, 75.50);
    displayProduct(deleted);

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * CHALLENGE :: Redo Problem #s 1 & 2 using either versions 3 or 4                       *
    * Keep in mind the changes when converting the ADT List Versions                 *
    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    getch();
    return 0;
}

/****************************************************************************************
 * This function initializes the list for its first use.                                     *
 ****************************************************************************************/
void initializeList(chocoList *L)
{
    *L = (chocoList)malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
    (*L)->prodCtr = 0;
}

/****************************************************************************************
 * This function populates the list by calling insertSorted().                          *
 ****************************************************************************************/
void populateSortedList(chocoList L)
{
    int x, result = 1;

    product data[] = {  {1501, "Hersheys", 100.50, 10},
                                {1502, "Hersheys Almond", 100.50, 15},
                                {1503, "Hersheys Krackel", 100.50, 15},
                                {1701, "Toblerone", 150.75, 20},
                                {1702, "Toblerone Milk", 150.75, 40},
                                {1703, "Toblerone Honey", 150.75, 10},
                                {1550, "Cadbury", 200.00, 30},
                                {1201, "Kitkat", 97.75, 40},
                                {1450, "Ferrero", 150.50, 50},
                                {1601, "Meiji", 75.50, 60},
                                {1301, "Nestle", 124.50, 70},
                                {1525, "Lindt", 175.50, 80},
                                {1545, "Valor", 100.50, 90},
                                {1455, "Tango", 49.50, 100}
                    };
    for(x = 0; x < 10 && result == 1; x++){
        result = insertSorted(L, data[x]);
    }                 
}

/****************************************************************************************
 * This function display the details of all products in the list.                       *
 ****************************************************************************************/            
void displayList(chocoList L, char * listName) 
{
    int x;
    system("CLS");       /* clears the screen before displaying succeeding lines */

    if(L->prodCtr != 0){
        printf("\nElements of the Product List %s:", listName);
        printf("\n\n%-10s%-15s%10s%10s","ID","Description","Price","Quantity");
        printf("\n%-10s%-15s%10s%10s","--","-----------","-----","--------");

        for(x = 0 ; x < L->prodCtr; x++){
            printf("\n%-10d", L->item[x].prodID);
            printf("%-15s", L->item[x].prodDesc);   
            printf("%10.2f", L->item[x].prodPrice);
            printf("%10d", L->item[x].prodQty);     
        }
    }else{
        printf("\n\tChoco list is currently empty!\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n Press any key to continue . . . ");
    getch();
}

/****************************************************************************************
 * This function inserts a product X in an alphabetically sorted list according to its  *
 * product description. It returns a value of 1 for successful insertion. Otherwise, 0. *
 * Use memcpy() in shifting the elements downward to provide space for the new product. *
 ***************************************************************************************/
int insertSorted(chocoList L, product X)
{
    int ctr;
    if(L->prodCtr<14){
        for(ctr=0; ctr<L->prodCtr && strcmp(L->item[ctr].prodDesc, X.prodDesc)<0;ctr++){    }
        memcpy(L->item + ctr + 1, L->item + ctr, sizeof(product) * (L->prodCtr - ctr));
        L->item[ctr] = X;
        L->prodCtr++;
        ctr = 1;
    }
    else{
        ctr = 0;
    }
    return ctr;
}

/****************************************************************************************
 * This function deletes the first occurence of a product given the prodPrice.It returns* 
 * the product record ones it is found. Otherwise, it returns a dummy record containing *
 * "XXX" for string values and 0 for integer and float values.  Use memcpy() in shifting *
 * the elements upward to avoid having empty indices within the array.                       *
 ***************************************************************************************/
product deleteFirstOccurence(chocoList L, float prodPrice)
{
    int ctr;
    product dummy;
    strcpy(dummy.prodDesc , "XXX");
    dummy.prodID = 0;
    dummy.prodPrice = 0;
    dummy.prodQty = 0;
    for(ctr = 0; ctr<L->prodCtr && L->item[ctr].prodPrice != prodPrice; ctr++){ }
    if(ctr!=L->prodCtr){
        dummy = L->item[ctr];
        memcpy(L->item + ctr, L->item + ctr + 1, sizeof(product) * (L->prodCtr - ctr));
        L->prodCtr--;
    }
    return dummy;
}

/****************************************************************************************
 * This function display the details of 1 product.                                       *
 ***************************************************************************************/
void displayProduct(product X)
{
    //system("CLS");       /* clears the screen before displaying succeeding lines */
    printf("\n\nElements of Product %d:", X.prodID);
    printf("\n\n%-10s%-15s%10s%10s","ID","Description","Price","Quantity");
    printf("\n%-10s%-15s%10s%10s","--","-----------","-----","--------");

    printf("\n%-10d", X.prodID);
    printf("%-15s", X.prodDesc);    
    printf("%10.2f", X.prodPrice);
    printf("%10d", X.prodQty);      

    printf("\n\n Press any key to continue . . . ");
    getch();    
}
```

I have a couple of questions with this part in particular:

```
int insertSorted(chocoList L, product X)
{
    int ctr;
    if(L->prodCtr<14){
        for(ctr=0; ctr<L->prodCtr && strcmp(L->item[ctr].prodDesc, X.prodDesc)<0;ctr++){    }
        memcpy(L->item + ctr + 1, L->item + ctr, sizeof(product) * (L->prodCtr - ctr));
        L->item[ctr] = X;
        L->prodCtr++;
        ctr = 1;
    }
    else{
        ctr = 0;
    }
    return ctr;
}
```

First of all, can someone explain to me this statement?

```
memcpy(L->item + ctr + 1, L->item + ctr, sizeof(product) * (L->prodCtr - ctr));
```

Second, is it more efficient to use `memcpy` or `memmove` in this scenario?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can Google some tutorials, or read a book about this

Comment: @stackptr it's cool. I already got my answer from user3386109.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memcpy` is attempting to move a portion of the array in order to make room for a new item. Visually, it's doing this:

[image]

where

- green is an item in the array that doesn't need to be moved
- blue is an item that needs to move to make room for the new item
- white is an unused item in the array
- yellow is the new item `X`

For the sake of this example, I've chosen these values:

- `L->prodCtr` is initially 6
- the `for` loop sets `ctr` to 3

So here's how the `memcpy` is supposed to work. The first argument (`L->item + ctr + 1`) is the destination address, which is the address of the first blue item ***after*** the move. The second argument `L->item + ctr` is the source address, which is the address of first blue item ***before*** the move. The third argument consists of two parts. `sizeof(product)` is the size of each item in bytes. `(L->prodCtr - ctr)` is the number of items that need to move. Multiply those together to get the number of bytes to move.

---

So that's what the `memcpy` is supposed to do. But, to answer your second question, you ***cannot*** use `memcpy` to do that. The reason is that `memcpy` only works if the source and destination ***do not overlap***. `memmove`, on the other hand, is guaranteed to work properly even if the source and destination do overlap. So there isn't any choice here, you must use `memmove`.

Comment: Have an up-vote for the pretty pictures - SO needs more pictures. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. You have no idea how much your answer means to me. I was already on the verge of giving up my course..

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, I'll add more pictures in the future :-)

Comment: @BoredChinese You're welcome, good luck with the class :-)

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, can someone explain to me this statement?

```
memcpy(L->item + ctr + 1, L->item + ctr, sizeof(product) * (L->prodCtr - ctr));
```

simply `memcpy()` function is copying the contents of size `sizeof(product) * (L->prodCtr - ctr)` present at `(L->item + ctr)` location to next location i.e. `(L->item + ctr + 1)`. Mean same contents would be copied to next location starting from `(L->item + ctr + 1)`

---

**Explaination**

`memcpy` is used in those places where you don't want to copy value of each member in a structure to another structure **manually** particularly when members are nested structures and pointer.

```
struct student 
{
unsigned int marks;
unsigned int reg;
};


struct student mazhar, abbas; 
mazhar.reg = 50;
mazhar.marks = 800;

/* First way. Manually Copy value of each member to destination structure */

abbas.reg = mazhar.reg;
abbas.marks = mazhar.marks;

/* Above method is useful when struct members are not too much. 
   But when you have many members of the structure i.e. like nested 
   structures etc. then you can use memcpy function. */ 

memcpy(&abbas, &mazhar, sizeof(struct student));
```